# Java Script Millisecond Issues

Tags: javascript, parsing, datetime

As w3schools say, Date.parse() returns *"the number of milliseconds between the date string and midnight of January 1, 1970."*

Which means that 
if I write Date.parse("January 1, 1970 00:00:00"), it should give me answer 0.

if I write Date.parse("January 1, 1970 00:00:05"), it should give me answer 5000.. But Im getting the **-14395000**... Why is that?

Comment: I'm getting 5000. Can you give us any more details (browser etc)?

Comment: Yeah me too: http://jsfiddle.net/vfQa4/1/

Comment: i'm getting -3595000. Date.parse("January 1, 1970 01:00:00") gives me 0 (chrome 34)

Comment: I'm in London, so @t.niese appears to have explained that in that answer.

Comment: Mozilla firefox 28.0: I'm getting: >>> Date.parse("January 01, 1970 00:00:05");
-17995000

Comment: Another example of why w3schools is bad. MDN explicitly mentions about timezones.

Comment: @casper123, what if you tried: `Date.parse("January 1, 1970 00:00:05 GMT+0500")`

Comment: @Andy: I tired Date.parse("January 1, 1970 00:00:05 GMT"); and it gives me correct 5000 milliseconds :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't specify a time zone so `January 1, 1970 00:00:00` is with the time offset of your timezone (or more precisely the one the browser has chosen for you). The milliseconds that are returned are relative to to the UTC.

**[MDN Date.parse:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)**

> The Date.parse() method parses a string representation of a date, and returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 **UTC**.

> [...] If you do not specify a time zone, the local time zone is assumed. GMT and UTC are considered equivalent. The local time zone is used to interpret arguments in [RFC2822 Section 3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14) format that do not contain time zone information. [...]